# Devtools for React Easy State?

Tags: reactjs, devtools, react-state-management, react-easy-state

i just switcher from redux, is there any tooling available, to inspect or even manipulate the react Easy State stores for dev purpose or do you have any good practice Tipps to do so?
Is ist maybe possible to console.log the current State on every change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have a devtool yet but it is an often requested feature. It's on our agenda and we are already collecting data about what people expect from a devtool. Sooo... what are the must-have features in a React state devtool to you?

About the timeline: we will release better docs, a linter, and probably strict-mode before a devtool. We already have a very basic devtool primitive (which just logs a lot of data) that could be used in the meantime. It would never be an official API though and we would just remove it in a later release. Are you interested? Should we release it as a temporary solution?

> Is ist maybe possible to console.log the current State on every change?

Sure:

```
import { store, autoEffect } from '@risingstack/react-easy-state'

const myStore = store({
  name: 'Bob'
})

autoEffect(() => console.log(JSON.stringify(myStore, null, 2)))

// logs `{ name: 'Ann' }`
myStore.name = 'Ann'
```

(I am an author of React Easy State)

Comment: thx a lot! 
regarding "must-have features in a React state devtool" , was pretty happy with the redux and vuex devtools, so:
* timetravel
* State Manipulation
* Listing of all States with keys and values

Comment: PS: an devtool/devlog sounds interesting , when one is able to active/deactivate it easy

Answer (score 1):

If you're using global stores, e.g.:

```
const myStore = store({
 a: 1
});
```

You can assign them to the window object so in your chrome/firefox devtools you could do something like:

```
window.__EASY_STORES__ = {
 MY_STORE: myStore
}
```

You can then mutate that object in the console and it should be reflected in the rendering if your components are wrapped in `view`.

Other than that there's currently discussion around building a whole suite of devtools in the community, but at the moment we don't provide any out of the box inspector or dev tooling around the library.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to log state changes using [middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware/). A simple logging middleware can look like this (it's typed in [Flow](https://flow.org/)):

```js
export default (store: Store<ReduxState>) => (
  next: (action: Action) => ReduxState
) => (action: Action) => {
  console.log(`dispatching: ${action.type}`)
  const result = next(action)
  console.log(`next state: ${JSON.stringify(store.getState())}`)
  return result
}
```

Manipulating is another thing. You could eather create a "cli" - I've recently done this [in a project](https://github.com/bbortt/Buessle-App/blob/7afe0a232f97832dedfbbc9c9785d1456462db76/src/main/webapp/src/redux/cli/dispatch.js). It's basically just a JS function exposed to the browsers console.

Or, what I would suggest is using a browser plugin. The most commonly known is probably "Redux DevTools" which is available at least for Firefox and Chrome. It gives you CRUD-control (create, read, update, delete) over `redux`-state.

**Edit:** Since I fataly misread your question, this [comment](https://github.com/RisingStack/react-easy-state/issues/14#issuecomment-553371764) on GitHub might interest you. Seems not to have very active maintainers^^ But sorry, I don't know anything about easy-state.

Comment: OP is not using redux but [easy state](https://github.com/RisingStack/react-easy-state)